# Cape Sandbox - problem with adding PeSieve tool as an auxiliary module - auxiliary module not implemented error

Tags: sandbox

I'm new to Python and Cape sandbox, I am trying to add Pe-Sieve tool in Cape when submitting an analysis through the Windows Guest, but it does not accept the code I have written, can you help me out? The goal is to execute pesieve in the check() function, while the payload sample is already running. I am also trying to run pe sieve by calling it using subrocess.....

This is what I came up with:

```
import subprocess
from lib.api.process import Process
from lib.common.exceptions import CuckooPackageError
from lib.common.abstracts import Auxiliary

class Pe(Auxiliary):

  """EXE analysis package."""


  def start(self):
    raise NotImplementedError


  def check(self):
   
    pe_sieve_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Pe-Sieve\pe-sieve64.exe"
    pe_sieve_args = ["-some_argument", "another_argument"]
    args = [pe_sieve_path] + pe_sieve_args
    try:
      subprocess.run(args, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
      raise CuckooPackageError(f"pe-sieve execution failed: {str(e)}")

    return True

  def execute(self, path, args):
    dll = self.options.get("dll")
    free = self.options.get("free")
    suspended = True

    if free:
      suspended = False

    p = Process()

    if not p.execute(path=path, args=args, suspended=suspended):
      raise CuckooPackageError("Unable to execute the initial process, " "analysis aborted.")


    if not free and suspended:
      p.inject(dll)
      p.resume()
      p.close()

      return p.pid


  def finish(self):

    if self.options.get("procmemdump"):

      for pid in self.pids:
        p = Process(pid=pid)
        p.dump_memory()
        return True
```